# How to use jplayer.swf, jplayer.js in a local disk, not in a web page

Tags: jplayer

If I put Jplayer.swf, jplayer.js and *.mp3 files in a local disk, for example "d:\mypage\MP3*.mp3", "d:\mypage\JS\jplayer.js", "d:\mypage\JS\Jplayer.swf" and "d:\mypage\mypage.htm",

swfPath = ¿?

I've tried many many different swfPath, but any of then work neither IE 8 nor FF

Can work in any way this configuration (in a local disk)?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the relative path:

```
swfPath = ".JS/Jplayer.swf";
```